# How to remove the scale indicator on y-axis

Tags: pgfplots, labels, axis

I would like to plot some data, whose y-coordinates are kind of small. I compiled with the following codes, and I ended up with an unexpected $10^{-2}$ on the y-axis (see the figure below). Is there a way to remove it? Thanks!

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel={$\theta$},
    ylabel={},
    axis line style = thick,
    xmin=-1, xmax=2.1,
    ymin=-0.015, ymax=0.025,
    ytick={}, yticklabels={}, 
    xtick={0,1}, xticklabels={$0$, $1$}, xtick style={draw=none}, ytick style={draw=none},
    legend style={at={(1.1,1)}},
    legend style={draw=none},
    ymajorgrids=false,
    grid style=dashed,
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
    anchor=west,},
    every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=south,
},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Reedited, thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `scaled ticks=false` option to switch off the common scaling factor:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel={$\theta$},
    ylabel={},
     scaled ticks=false,
    axis line style = thick,
    xmin=-1, xmax=2.1,
    ymin=-0.015, ymax=0.025,
    ytick={}, yticklabels={}, 
    xtick={0,1}, xticklabels={$0$, $1$}, xtick style={draw=none}, ytick style={draw=none},
    legend style={at={(1.1,1)}},
    legend style={draw=none},
    ymajorgrids=false,
    grid style=dashed,
    every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
    anchor=west,},
    every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
    anchor=south,
},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An example of (really) MWE (Minimal Working Example) which solve your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    axis line style = thick,
    xlabel={$\theta$}, 
    xlabel style={at={(1,0)},anchor=west},
    xmin=-1,        xmax=2.1,
    ymin=-0.015,    ymax=0.025,
    xtick={0,1}, 
    tick style={draw=none}, 
    ytick=\empty,
%    extra y ticks = {0.005,0.01},   % if needed some thicks
    legend style={at={(1.1,1)}, draw=none},
]
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `ytick=\empty,`  which makes tikz put nothing in the y axis ticks.

Comment: Thanks, but I do need to have some ticks on the y-axis eventually. Is there a way to enable this while keep the 10^2 invisible?