# How to remove the exponent on axis in pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots

I am looking for removing the `$10^{-2}$` that is automatically displayed on my y-axis.
I tried to put my own labels but it does not work.
I don't want to change my values as my drawings depend on it.

[image]

Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
        height          =   10cm,
        width           =   10cm,
        xlabel          =   {\Large $1-T_{0}\text{(a.u.)}$ },
        ylabel          =   {\Large $A_{peak}\text{(a.u)}$},
        ytick           =   {0,0.002,0.004,0.006,0.008,0.01,0.012},
        yticklabels     =   {0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1.2},
        legend style    =   
        {draw=none, legend columns = 1, legend pos = north west},
        legend entries  =   {$200\text{km}-$ pd,$225\text{km}-$ pd,
                            $200\text{km}-$ corr,$225\text{km}-$ corr},
        ]
        % ------------------- PD
        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark        = *,
            mark size   = 5pt,
            color       = black,
            error bars/.cd,
            y dir       = both,
            y explicit,
            ]
            table[x=losslin, y=Apeak0km, y error = 3std0km, col sep= comma]
            {./PeakValuesArticlePD.txt};
        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark        = pentagon*,
            mark size   = 5pt,
            color       = orange,
            error bars/.cd,
            y dir       = both,
            y explicit,
            ]
            table[x=losslin, y=Apeak25km, y error = 3std25km, col sep= comma]
            {./PeakValuesArticlePD.txt};
        % ------------------- Corr
        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark        = *,
            mark size   = 3pt,
            color       = gray,
            error bars/.cd,
            y dir       = both,
            y explicit,
            ]
            table[x=losslin, y=Apeak0km, y error = 3std0km, col sep= comma]
            {./PeakValuesArticleCorrection.txt};
        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark        = pentagon*,
            mark size   = 3pt,
            color       = blue,
            error bars/.cd,
            y dir       = both,
            y explicit,
            ]
            table[x=losslin, y=Apeak25km, y error = 3std25km, col sep= comma]
            {./PeakValuesArticleCorrection.txt};
        % ------------------- fit 100 [km]
        \addplot [
            color           = black,
            line width      = 0.75pt,
            domain          = 0:1,
            samples         = 3,
            forget plot,
            ]
            {0.0110527*x+0.00021931}; % PeakValuesArticlePD
%            {0.00112158*x+0.000136995}; % PeakValuesArticleCorrection
            
        \draw (axis cs:0.45,0.0073) node[rotate = 45,gray,below = 1pt]
            {\large ${S_{200}^{(corr)}=1.122\cdot 10^{-2}}$};
            
        \draw (axis cs:0.60,0.0068)--(axis cs:0.65,0.0068)-- (axis cs:0.65,0.0074) 
            node[midway,below,rotate = 45]
            {\large ${S_{200}^{(pd)}=1.105\cdot 10^{-2}}$};
            
        % ------------------- fit 125 [km]
        \addplot [
            color           = black,
            line width      = 0.75pt,
            domain          = 0:1,
            samples         = 3,
            forget plot,
            ]
            {0.00336964*x+0.000133969}; % PeakValuesArticlePD
%            {0.00354502*x+0.0000695078}; % PeakValuesArticleCorrection
            
        \draw (axis cs:0.55,0.0038) node[blue, below = 9pt, rotate = 15]
            {\large ${S_{225}^{(corr)} = 3.545\cdot 10^{-3}}$};
            
        \draw (axis cs:0.60,0.00214)--(axis cs:0.7,0.00214)--(axis cs:0.7,0.00251)
            node[midway, below, orange,rotate = 15]
            {\large ${S_{225}^{(pd)} = 3.369\cdot 10^{-3}}$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

my data are:

`PeakValuesArticleCorrection.txt`:

```
lossdB,losslin,Apeak0km,Apeak25km,std0km,std25km,3std0km,3std25km

1.25,0.25,0.002904,0.000958,3.36E-05,2.09E-05,0.000100733590671,6.27E-05

3,0.499,0.005783,0.001841,2.12E-05,1.86E-05,6.37E-05,5.57E-05

6,0.749,0.008581,0.002722,2.08E-05,1.32E-05,6.24E-05,3.97E-05

9,0.874,0.00987,0.003134,2.74E-05,1.62E-05,8.23E-05,4.87E-05

12,0.937,0.01066,0.003423,3.20E-05,1.55E-05,9.61E-05,4.66E-05
```

`PeakValuesArticlePD.txt`:

```
losslin,Apeak0km,Apeak25km,std0km,std25km,3std0km,3std25km

0.25,0.00291,0.00096,3.15E-05,2.61E-05,9.45E-05,7.83E-05

0.499,0.00578,0.00182,2.35E-05,1.97E-05,7.05E-05,5.91E-05

0.749,0.00864,0.0027,3.17E-05,2.50E-05,9.51E-05,7.5E-05

0.874,0.00993,0.0031,2.8E-05,2.64E-05,8.4E-05,7.92E-05

0.937,0.01041,0.00324,1.85E-05,2.44E-05,5.55E-05,7.32E-05
```

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669412/36296 help?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thx! How to put a thumb up on your answer?

Comment: You're welcome! (don't worry about thumbs up - I think voting requires 20 reputation points, so with your 11 ones you are already half way there :) )