tikz: remove the * 10^4 at the end of the xaxis
im plotting a tikzpicture and want to remove the annotation at the end of my x-axis.
(*10^4) do you know how to fix it?
here is my tikzplot:
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{darkgray176}{RGB}{176,176,176}
\definecolor{darkorange25512714}{RGB}{255,127,14}
\definecolor{lightgray204}{RGB}{204,204,204}
\definecolor{steelblue31119180}{RGB}{31,119,180}

\begin{axis}[
legend cell align={left},
legend style={fill opacity=0.8, draw opacity=1, text opacity=1, draw=lightgray204},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
title={Temperatur},
x grid style={darkgray176},
xlabel={Datum},
xmin=16542.65, xmax=16550.35,
xtick style={color=black},
xtick={16543,16544,16545,16546,16547,16548,16549,16550},
xticklabel style={rotate=30.0,anchor=east},
xticklabels={18-Apr,19-Apr,20-Apr,21-Apr,22-Apr,23-Apr,24-Apr,25-Apr},
y grid style={darkgray176},
ylabel={clinkerBrickOutside.cap.T},
ymin=275.515933964339, ymax=310.469969967142,
ytick style={color=black}
]

...
here is the picture, thank you very much!


Please post a full minimal working example (MWE), that we can compile and which reproduces your issue. Use also code blocks: highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it)

Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669412/36296 help?

Welcome .......
